# ScrollViewer's Viewport Height VS Actual Height

Tags: wpf, listbox, virtualization, scrollviewer, actualheight

Both are quite general terms but I'm curious to know when these height will be different apart from the case we're using Virtualization?

One more question:
I read on MSDN:

*If CanContentScroll is true, the values of the ExtentHeight, ScrollableHeight, ViewportHeight, and VerticalOffset properties are number of items. If CanContentScroll is false, the values of these properties are Device Independent Pixels.*

However I'm facing an issue with ViewPort Height: I've 2 listbox in application:
 1. Which have Virtualization Enabled and CanContentScroll = True.
 2. Which have no virtualization and CanContentScroll = True.

In ListBox 1 while drag-drop Viewport Height comes to 4/5 (Number of elements currently visible). However in ListBox 2 i get Viewport Height equal to Actual Height of Listbox.

Why this difference?

Few more findings:
*1. Scrollable Height is number of items not visible in scrollviewer

2. Viewport Height is number of items visible in scrollviewer.

Thus Viewport Height + ScrollableHeight = Extent Height*

*Can someone please explain what's the difference between two listboxes? I need ViewPort hieght in case of Listbox 1*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally This was the root cause:

Quoting from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3062692/3195477:

> You are encountering the differences between physical scrolling and
> logical scrolling.
>
> As you have discovered, each has its tradeoffs.
>
> **Physical scrolling**
>
> Physical scrolling (CanContentScroll=false) just goes by pixels, so:
>
> The viewport always represents exactly the same portion of your scroll
> extent, giving you a smooth scrolling experience, and but
>
> The entire contents of the DataGrid must have all templates fully
> applied and be measured and arranged to determine the size of the
> scrollbar, leading to long delays during loading and high RAM usage,
> and It doesn't really scroll items so it doesn't understand
> ScrollIntoView very well Logical scrolling
>
> **Logical scrolling** (CanContentScroll=true) calculates its scroll viewport and extent by items instead of pixels, so:
>
> The viewport may show a different number of items at different times,
> meaning the number of items in the viewport as compared to the number
> of items in the extent varies, causing the scrollbar length to change,
> and
>
> Scrolling moves from one item to the next and never in between,
> leading to "jerky" scrolling
>
> but
>
> As long as you're using VirtualizingStackPanel under the hood, it only
> needs to apply templates and measure and arrange the items that are
> actually visible at the moment, and
>
> ScrollIntoView is much simpler since it just needs to get the right
> item index into view
>
> **Choosing between them**
>
> These are the only two kinds of scrolling provided by WPF. You must
> choose between them based on the above tradeoffs. Generally logical
> scrolling is best for medium to large datasets, and physical scrolling
> is best for small ones.
>
> A trick to speed loading during physical scrolling is to make the
> physical scrolling better is to wrap your items in a custom Decorator
> that has a fixed size and sets its child's Visibility to Hidden when
> it is not visible. This prevents the ApplyTemplate, Measure and
> Arrange from occuring on the descendant controls of that item until
> you're ready for it to happen.
>
> A trick to make physical scrolling's ScrollIntoView more reliable is
> to call it twice: Once immediately and once in a dispatcher callback
> of DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle.
>
> Making logical scroll scrollbar more stable
>
> If all your items are the same height, the number of items visible in
> the viewport at any time will stay the same, causing the scroll thumb
> size to stay the same (because the ratio with total number if items
> doesn't change).
>
> It is also possible to modify the behavior of the ScrollBar itself so
> the thumb is always calculated to be a fixed size. To do this without
> any hacky code-behind:
>
> - Subclass Track to replace the    calculation of Thumb position and    size in MeasureOverride with your own
> - Change the ScrollBar template used       for the logical-scrolling ScrollBar      to use your subclassed Track instead     of the regular
>   one
> - Change the    ScrollViewer template    to explicitly    set your custom    ScrollBar template on    the    logical-scrolling ScrollBar
>   (instead of using the default       template)
> - Change the ListBox template    to use    explicitly set your custom       ScrollViewer template on the       ScrollViewer it creates
>
> This means copying a lot of template code fom the built-in WPF
> templates, so it is not a very elegant solution. But the alternative
> to this is to use hacky code-behind to wait until all the templates
> are expanded, then find the ScrollBar and just replace the ScrollBar
> template with the one that uses your custom Track. This code saves two
> large templates (ListBox, ScrollViewer) at the cost of some very
> tricky code.
>
> Using a different Panel would be a much larger amount of work:
> VirtualizingStackPanel is the only Panel that virtualizes, and only it
> and StackPanel to logical scrolling. Since you are taking advantage of
> VirtualizingStackPanel's virtualization abilities you would have to
> re-implement all of these plus all IScrollInfo info function plus your
> regular Panel functions. I could do something like that but I would
> allocate several, perhaps many, days to get it right. I recommend you
> not try it.

Comment: next time you're posting a question post all relevant information right from the start. You could have for example stated that you are talking about a ScrollViewer inside an ItemsControl which is a totally different scenario than the usual ScrollViewer that just lets you scroll through some content.

Answer (score 12):

the `ActualHeight` is the actual height of the ScrollViewer. The Viewport is what is visible from the ScrollViewers Content. So to answer your question: `ViewportHeight` differs from `ActualHeight` if the horizontal Scrollbar is visible by the `Height` of the Scrollbar.

so, to sum this up:

```
ActualHeight = ViewportHeight + HorizontalScrollbarHeight
```

Comment: Can you please explain the relation between horizontal scrollbar visibility with Viewport Height ????

Comment: @Rohit didn't I already? Here a specific example: The ActualHeight is 200px. The Horizontal Scrollbar has a height of 12px. If the Horizontal Scrollbar _is_ shown, the Viewport Height is 188px, if it _is not_ shown the Viewport height is 200px. And whether the Scrollbar is shown depends on the Property `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I understand this thing (said above) but I'm curious to know how these things are related to each other. As much i understand Viewport Height should work considering ActualHeight & Vertical Scrollbar visibility.

Comment: @Rohit I don't really know what more to explain. The Viewport's size is that of the ScrollViewer minus the area of the Scrollbars. you can only __get__ the Viewport's dimensions (not set it). It gets calculated depending on the ActualHeight (whicht itsself is readonly and also gets calculated (by the `Height` property and restraints on the control)) and the scrollbars. It exists so you can bind to it and don't have to use a valueconverter to calculate `ActualHeight - (IsHorizontalScrollBarVisible ? HorizontalScrollbarHeight : 0)`.

Comment: This asnwer is only correct for the cases when `CanContentScroll` is `false` The viewport height of a  `ScrollViewer` in a `ListView` for example will always be the number of items the `ScrollViewer`can display.

Comment: @bitbonk this answer addressed the question in its original form. It wasn't apparent until after OP edited it, that he was actually talking about a `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

They can differ from the point of (specified) `Height` being evaluated to any given time during the (ongoing) rendering process.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx):

> There is a difference between the
>   properties of Height and Width and
>   ActualHeight and ActualWidth. For
>   example, the ActualHeight property is
>   a calculated value based on other
>   height inputs and the layout system.
>   The value is set by the layout system
>   itself, based on an actual rendering
>   pass, and may therefore lag slightly
>   behind the set value of properties,
>   such as Height, that are the basis of
>   the input change.
>
> Because ActualHeight
>   is a calculated value, you should be
>   aware that there could be multiple or
>   incremental reported changes to it as
>   a result of various operations by the
>   layout system. The layout system may
>   be calculating required measure space
>   for child elements, constraints by the
>   parent element, and so on.