# Get items in view within a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox with the property VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode set to "Recycling".
I am binding a custom collection (implements `IList` and `IList<T>`) to it.

Now, if I understand right, when data is bound, GetEnumerator is called.
And then property `public T this[int index]  { }` is called for every item in the current view.

My question is how to get the items that are currently visible (after the data is loaded)?

Comment: You have an answer here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187382/get-listview-visible-items

Answer (score 3):

Sometime back i also faced the same issue. I found a workaround of my problem by using "SelectedItem" of Listbox as selected item would be visible always.  In my case it was Scrolling which was causing issue. You can have a look if it helps -
[Virtualization issue in listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777630/consolidated-scrolling-pixel-by-pixel-item-by-item)

Also - [Virtualization scrollview - Good One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733738/scrollviewers-viewport-height-vs-actual-height)

Comment: I don't see why item selection automatically means the item is visible, it could very well be selected but not in view.

Comment: :).Developers are now used to of it.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to figure out something similar, I thought I would share my result here (as it seems easier than the other responses):

Simple visibility test I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517743/in-wpf-how-can-i-determine-whether-a-control-is-visible-to-the-user).

```
private static bool IsUserVisible(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement container)
{
    if (!element.IsVisible)
        return false;

    Rect bounds =
        element.TransformToAncestor(container).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight));
    var rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, container.ActualWidth, container.ActualHeight);
    return rect.Contains(bounds.TopLeft) || rect.Contains(bounds.BottomRight);
}
```

Afterwards you can loop through the ListBoxItems and use that test to determine which are visible.

```
private List<object> GetVisibleItemsFromListbox(ListBox listBox, FrameworkElement parentToTestVisibility)
{
    var items = new List<object>();

    foreach (var item in PhotosListBox.Items)
    {
        if (IsUserVisible((ListBoxItem)listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item), parentToTestVisibility))
        {
            items.Add(item);
        }
        else if (items.Any())
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return items;
}
```