# WPF ListView scroll whole page (seen items) by button click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've created a listview in WPF. The items in there are changing their backgroundcolor by clicking, in this case i deactivated the listview prop 'Focusable'. 
For my usecase (on a touchscreen) i want to hide the scrollbar and just scroll by clicking an up/down button at the bottom. One click should scroll the **whole page** (UP/DOWN) and show the next (so far hided) items.
I'm seraching for a flexible solution and don't want to calculate pixels or smth like that (also the items haven't a fixed height, also the window)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First off, it might benefit you to take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, in your case it would be easier to understand the sitution if you included some of your XAML. However, I do think I have a solution for you.

`ItemsControl`s like the `ListView` support "content scrolling", meaning the ability to scroll by content/items instead of by pixel. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187382/get-listview-visible-items) gives a solution to finding which items are currently visible in the `ListView` by accessing the internal `ScrollViewer`. `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` will tell you the index first visible item and `ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight` will tell you how many items are visible. To scroll to the "next page", you should just need to:

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset += ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight;
```