# WPF Datagrid scrolls up a bit when scrolled to end

Tags: wpf, performance, scrollbar, wpfdatagrid, drag

I have a WPF Datagrid (4.0 on Win7). When it is scrolled to very end by dragging ([after dragging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vexfU.gif)) the thumb it sometimes returns a bit when released and mouse cursor moves away (probably to start with a complete line).  I tried to set CanContentScroll  property of DG_ScrollViewer (see [WPF DataGrid : CanContentScroll property causing odd behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062540/wpf-datagrid-cancontentscroll-property-causing-odd-behavior)) but the grid become unusably slow when populated with lot of data.

The problem doesn't occur when scrolling is done by mouse wheel ([after scrolling with wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4KBC.gif)) or clicking a scrollbar arrow.

The problem occures also with horizontal scroling.!

Comment: Interesting. On my system, wpf datagrids always skip a full row when scrolling, even dragging the thumb. The top of the datagrid always aligns with the top of a row. I cannot get it to scroll, say, half-a-row in order to cause the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: Maybe it is connected with  EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" but I did not tried to remove it.

Comment: No. Those properties don't seem to make a difference in what I'm seeing.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: The effect is much more significant when bottom lines are higher (multi line text).

Comment: Are you sure its not your mouse that's actually bouncing up, causing the thumb to scroll? I don't see why the mouse wheel should be any different than the scroll bar.

Comment: @Tyrsius: You mean that I somehow release the thumb. It could be, but I saw the problem disappear with CanContentScroll = false and the problem was observed (with the same program) by 5 people on 5 computers with different data.

Comment: Well then you sound like you found it! You should make an answer and mark it.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez: Thanks. Your aswer said me it's not a WPF bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found the reason. There was a handler causing the behavior.

```
Private Sub mMainGrid_PreviewMouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles MyGrid.PreviewMouseUp
        If TypeOf e.OriginalSource Is Thumb Then
            MyGrid.Items.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub
```

The aim of this handler is to force refresh a header when a column is resized.