# WPF Datagrid with AlternatingRowBackground scrolls differently when scrolled up and down

Tags: wpf, scroll, row, wpfdatagrid, alternating

I have a WPF(4.0 on Win7) datagrid with AlternatingRowBackground when I scroll up row colors remain on place and data are moving when I scroll down colors are moving with data. **Is it usual? Is it possible to get rid of this strange behavior?**

**Grid XAML:**

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Name="grdData" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}" SelectionMode="Single"
                      HeadersVisibility="All" 
                      AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" 
                      />
```

**Note:** I have other question about scrolling ( [WPF Datagrid scrolls up a bit when scrolled to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601687/wpf-datagrid-scrolls-up-a-bit-when-scrolled-to-end) ) but I am not sure whether problems are connected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `EnableRowVirtualization="False"` to your datagrid.

Comment: You are right. I'll take it if there is no better solution (I need virtualization for performance).

Comment: Completely understandable. I'll check back to see if anything better is suggested.

Answer (score -1):

This trigger works with **EnableRowVirtualization="True"**

```
<DataGrid Name="dg" Style="{DynamicResource estiloDG}" MinRowHeight="40" GridLinesVisibility="None" 
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray" VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
          BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="#424242"
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=ItemsSource, Mode=OneWay}" x:FieldModifier="Private" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True">

    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFD0E8D0" />
                </Trigger>                  
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>

<DataGrid.Resources>  
    <Style x:Key="estiloDG" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderHeight" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="HeadersVisibility" Value="All" />
        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="{StaticResource RowBackgroundBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHorizontalLinesBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="{StaticResource DataGridHorizontalLinesBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="CellStyle" Value="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" />
        <Setter Property="RowValidationErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ErrorTemplate2}" />
        <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{StaticResource DatagridColumnHeaderCustomTemplateStyle}" />      
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Sorry to hear that, we have this piece of code working in production environment with target 4.0

Comment: I'll look at it again.

Comment: Adding the `<DataGrid.RowStyle>` through `</DataGrid.RowStyle>` block to my DataGrid XAML had no effect.  Unless I changed "White" to a different color, then I'd get a grid of all that one color.  Is there another setting outside this block that is required?

Comment: My answer is edited with the code working. Sorry for the delay!.

Comment: Doesn't work at all, is it in the style you didn't post? There isn't even an AlternationCount property set.

Comment: I apologise, I didn't include the style with AlternationCount = 2.
I hope it solves the problem